# No sound on USB-C external monitor with bootcamp

Tags: display, audio, bootcamp, usb

I have a MacBook Pro 16" 2019 model and a Samsung S32AM700URXEN monitor that is connected to the MacBook with a USB-C cable. The video is perfect but the sound is playing on the MacBook instead of the monitor when using Windows with Bootcamp. The same setup works fine under macOS.

In **System Preferences** > **Sound**> **Output** there is only one option, and that is the Apple audio device. So is there a separate driver that needs to be installed?

Comment: Which version of Windows is your MacBook Pro running? Samsung seems to have a Windows driver for your monitor: https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/LS32AM700URXEN/#downloads. Can you check it and report back? (Alternatively, you can have Windows automatically download recommended drivers, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware-0549a8d9-4842-8acb-75fa-a6faadb62507 for more information).

Comment: Windows Update has no suggestions?   Windows has a problem solver that can fix many problems.  It might work for you .

Comment: @jaume I have installed the drivers, there was even a choice to make (HDMI or USB-C version) which seemed pretty promising, but in the end didn't change anything. I have installed the 22H2 windows update, but I'm having problems with the latest updates. I think that's because I don't have a system reserve partition. Probably Bootcamp didn't create one. But still, Windows is pretty up to date and this display is not that new.
These are my Windows specs:
Edition Windows 10 Home N
Version 22H2
Installed on ‎12/‎19/‎2022
OS build 19045.2364
Experience Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Comment: I decided to reinstall Windows (it had another more frustrating issue) The sound problem is solved, even though the update is still stuck on the same problem. So it was something else, but we will never find out what.